# With a sequence $a_n$ that satisfies $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_{n} - a_{n-2})=0$, prove or disprove this statement

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I am stuck finding a way to prove/disprove this limit of a sequence.

Assuming that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_{n} - a_{n-2})=0$ for the sequence $a_n$, prove or disprove that

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n} - a_{n-1}}{n}=0.$$

An explanation on how to work this through would be very appreciated.

Comment: The statement is false. You can show this as follows. On the odd-numbered indices construct a sequence that converges to $0$, whereas on the even-numbered indices construct a sequence that diverges to infinity at least as quickly as $n$, and whose members gets ever closer to each other.

Comment: @EvanAad - But with the condition that $\lim_{k \to \infty} a_{2k} - a_{2(k-1)} = 0$ how can your even-numbered indices diverge to infinity as quickly as $n$?

Comment: @EvanAad: Then the initial condition will not hold for the even-numbered indices.

Comment: @mlg4080: You're right. My mistake. Sorry.

Comment: @barakmanos: You're right. My mistake. Sorry.

Comment: @clark I saw that post but was confused how one of the user answers by user149418 arrived at the expression for $x_n$? Or even explain what $b_n$ represents, as it is not defined in the problem? (http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1147157/375657)

Comment: Then ask for explanations on the other page instead of posting a duplicate.

Comment: And I have no idea why you concentrated exclusively on the answer you cite, which frankly I do not want to dissect, while two others solve very clearly the question...

Comment: @Did My bad, that answer seemed to be the most thorough but I was confused on the sequence referenced so I am looking for a different approach/explanation

Comment: "so I am looking for a different approach/explanation" Good news, there are TWO on the other page.

Comment: @Did unfortunately I cant comment on the existing post due to my low rep on this board so I am unable to ask for any clarification

Comment: Once again: why the fixation on this answer? There are tons of defective posts on the site, just focus on the non defective ones. (Are you the author of the duplicate to the present post?)

Comment: @Did I only reference that post because it is the only one I can find with the same question parameters. I am not the author of any other post on this topic

Answer (score 0):

For any fixed $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $N = N_\epsilon$ such that $|a_n - a_{n-2}| < \epsilon$ for all $n > N$. Thus $|a_{N+2k} - a_{N}| < \epsilon k$ and $|a_{N+2k+1} - a_{N+1}| < \epsilon k$ for $k>0$. And so

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{|a_n - a_{n-1}|}{n} &\leq& \frac{|a_n - a_{N + n\%2}| + |a_{N} - a_{N+1}| + |a_{n-1} - a_{N + (n-1)\%2}|}{n} \\
&< &\frac{\epsilon \frac{n}{2} + |a_N - a_{N+1}| + \epsilon \frac{n}{2}}{n} \to \epsilon,
\end{eqnarray}

where $r\%2$ is the remainder when $r$ is divided by $2$.

Comment: @Danny_Rorabaugh Your first statement is wrong. Consider $a_{2k} = \sum_{n=1}^{2k} \frac{1}{n}$. Then $\lim_{k \to \infty} a_{2k} - a_{2(k-1)} = 0$ but it does not converge.

Comment: @mlg4080 D'oh! Thanks for catching that. My second attempt is (hopefully) less careless.