# Show that if $\lim(x_n - x_{n-2}) = 0$ then $\lim(\frac{x_n - x_{n-1}}{n}) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I know that $\frac{1}{n}$ converges to zero. So if I can show that $x_n - x_{n-1}$  is bounded then by the squeeze theorem, I would have the desired result. I have tried to show that $x_n - x_{n-1}$ is bounded by seeing $(x_n -  x_{n-2}$ as a Cauchy sequence but I am not getting anywhere.

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1146891/42969 – both found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bn%20%5Cto%20%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7Bx_n%20-%20x_%7Bn-1%7D%7D%7Bn%7D%20%3D%200%24&p=1)